# Resource not found Exception in Android Studio 3.0.1 (android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception)

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

I am a newbie in Android Development and recently I started using Android Studio. I am working on a entire project where I need to translate all text to English and Spanish. (I come from iOS)

So this is my step to get this done:

Setup my values/strings.xml and es/strings.xml like this:

[image]

And try to use this in my class:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class MainMenuItem {

    int image;
    String title;
    Class activity;


    public MainMenuItem(int image, String title, Class activity) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Class getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public static List<MainMenuItem> getItems() {
        List<MainMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        items.add(new MainMenuItem(R.drawable.icon_qr_code, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.mainMenuItem_validar_voucher), QrcodeActivity.class)); //this line is how i try to use.
        items.add(new MainMenuItem(R.drawable.icon_get_money,"Solicitar pago", SolicitarPagoActivity.class));
        items.add(new MainMenuItem(R.drawable.icon_promotions, "Promociones", ListaPromosActivity.class));

        return items;
    }
}
```

But, when I run the project give this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0800ad
```

Comment: How are you calling the `MainMenuItem`  class ?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is kind of late, but I was struggling with similar problem. In my case, the problem originated from the different drawable directories in the res folder in the project view. I had a couple of resources placed in the "drawable-hdpi" which was not available in the general "drawable" directory. Therefore, everytime that I tried to run the app on the low-res devices such as some of the tablets, I got the resource-not-found error. Always make sure that all the resources are available for the default directory. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you simply put in the string, `Validar Voucher` as the second parameter in `items.add()`, however if you are persistent on wanting to use resources, then you need to **just** use `getResources().getText(R.string.mainMenuItem_validar_voucher)`.

The syntax to reference a resource is `[<package_name>.]R.<resource_type>.<resource_name>`

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Using XML string resources allows easier localization than hardcoding strings (don't hardcode strings in production!). This doesn't solve the problem where `Resources` object comes from (use `context.getResources()` rather than `Resources.getSystem()`).

Answer (score -1):

`R.string.mainMenuItem_validar_voucher` is a resource identifier to *your app's resource* not system resource. You're going to have to use Context provided by your app to resolve it.

Since you're supposed to provide all your UI strings via XML resources (for easy translation) I suggest you modify your `MainMenuItem` class as such:

```
public class MainMenuItem {
    @DrawableRes private final int imageId;
    @StringRes private final int titleId;
    @NonNull private final Class<Activity> activity;

    public MainMenuItem(@DrawableRes int imageId, @StringRes int titleId, @NonNull Class<Activity> activity) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.titleId = titleId;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @StringRes
    public int getTitleId() {
        return titleId;
    }

    // Helper method to directly resolve the title.
    public String getTitle(Context context) {
        return context.getString(title);
    }

    @DrawableRes
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    // Helper method to directly resolve the image.
    public Drawable getImage(Context context) {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, image);
    }

    @NonNull
    public Class<Activity> getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
}
```

Here's the updated item list definition:

```
public class MainMenuItem {
    private static List<MainMenuItem> ITEMS;

    // It's more efficient to precompute the item list once
    // than to create it every time you call `getItems()`.

    // Notice how only resource IDs to both image and title are stored.

    static {
        List<MainMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new MainMenuItem(R.drawable.icon_qr_code, R.string.mainMenuItem_validar_voucher, QrcodeActivity.class));
        items.add(new MainMenuItem(R.drawable.icon_get_money, R.string.mainMenuItem_solicitar_pago, SolicitarPagoActivity.class));
        items.add(new MainMenuItem(R.drawable.icon_promotions, R.string.mainMenuItem_promociones, ListaPromosActivity.class));
        ITEMS = Collections.unmodifiableList(items);
    }

    public static List<MainMenuItem> getItems() {
        return ITEMS;
    }
}
```

Now whenever you need the image or the title you'd call `item.getImage(context)` or `item.getTitle(context)` respectively where `context` may be

- `this` in `Activity`
- `view.getContext()`

Comment: Hi... thanks for the reply.. can continue help me?  i copy your code and i get errors: 1. error: cannot find symbol class StringRes 2. error: cannot find symbol class Context .  ....how can solved this? thanks!

Comment: ok the error 1 i solved whit this line: import android.support.annotation.StringRes;   but the error 2 still have

Comment: more error:  error: cannot find symbol class Activity .  help me pls

Comment: @xhinoda I left out the import statements intentionally. Are you using Android Studio? Place text cursor in "Activity", press Alt+Enter, select "Import class". Do this with all missing references.